# PowerShell group policy issue

Tags: c#, winforms

The '`Get-GPO`' command was found in the module '`Group Policy`', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run '`Import-Module Group Policy`'. Please do suggest me using c#.

I am trying to import Group policy for the remote PC of the domains.When I invoke the command I get above Issue .

Comment: I suppose the first part of your question is the error you got ? If then please edit and organize your question so that it is easier to understand. Also please include the steps/commands you tried.

Comment: Yes.The question is in proper format,Please help me in getting the expected result. @gvmani